# Aligning a Gridview in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i know this is really basic. i am creating a grid in visual studio 2010. i want  to center align the grid. Not the data but the grid. it should appear in the middle of the page. can anyone tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [HorizontalAlign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.horizontalalign.aspx) property of the GridView

> Gets or sets the horizontal alignment of a GridView control on the
>   page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" >
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a width for your gridview and then set margin-left/right to auto

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .CenteredGrid { width:640px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
    </style>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="CenteredGrid">
     ... Codes ...
    </asp:GridView>
```

Edit:

This will work the same for any control/element on your page.

Answer (score 2):

make a div with center align and put your grid view inside it

```
   <div align="center">
    // put your gridview here
    </div>
```